# TensorFlow 2.0 clip_by_value with dynamic bounds

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

It is not clear from the TensorFlow documentation whether I can have dynamic range constraints imposed on a `tf.Variable` via `tf.clip_by_value`. From my testing it doesn't seem to work, but I would like to be sure, and if it isn't then I also would like to know how to achieve this (there are certain parts of my parameter space that cause NaNs in my loss function, and these constraints can only be described in terms of combinations of parameters).

Here is my test scenario:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd
import numpy as np

N = 2
Ntrials = 100
x = [tf.Variable(np.zeros(Ntrials,dtype='float32'), name='x{0}'.format(i)) for i in range(N)]
eta = [tf.Variable(np.zeros(Ntrials,dtype='float32'),
  constraint=lambda z: tf.clip_by_value(z, -x[i] + 0.0001, np.infty), name='eta{0}'.format(i))
   for i in range(N)]
# i.e. x[i] + eta[i] should always be positive

cov = [[1.0, 0.0],[0.0,1.0]]
mvn0 = tfd.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance([1,1],cov)

# Get samples
samples0 = mvn0.sample(Ntrials) # Ntrials)

print("samples.shape:", samples0.shape)

# Get pdf values for samples
etax = None
def get_loss():
   global etax
   etax = [xi + etai for xi,etai in zip(x,eta)]
   # Need to stack eta variables for broadcasting in MultivariateNormalFullCovariance
   all_etax = tf.stack(etax, axis=1, name='all_eta')
   #print("all_eta.shape:", all_eta.shape)
   mvnfree = tfd.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(all_etax,cov)
   p = mvnfree.log_prob(samples0)
   #print("p:",p)
   return -2*tf.math.reduce_sum(p,axis=0)

# Minimise
tol = 0.01 * N
delta_loss = 1e9
prev_loss = 1e9
i = 0
print("tol:", tol)
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD(0.1)
while delta_loss > tol:
    opt.minimize(get_loss,var_list=eta+x)
    last_loss = get_loss()  
    delta_loss = np.abs(prev_loss -last_loss)
    print("i:", i, " delta_loss:", delta_loss)
    tf.print("  x:", x)
    tf.print("  eta:", eta)
    tf.print("  etax:", etax)
    i+=1
    prev_loss = last_loss

print("Finished!")
```

Output:

```
samples.shape: (100, 2)
tol: 0.02
i: 0  delta_loss: 999999400.0
  x: [[0.186258137 0.269369602 0.520818532 ... 0.354108274 0.137650698 0.25976041], [-0.149198815 0.34362933 0.128372893 ... 0.391129225 0.239100441 0.264151126]]
  eta: [[0.186258137 0.269369602 0.520818532 ... 0.354108274 0.137650698 0.25976041], [0.0001 0.34362933 0.128372893 ... 0.391129225 0.239100441 0.264151126]]
  etax: [[0.372516274 0.538739204 1.04163706 ... 0.708216548 0.275301397 0.519520819], [-0.149098814 0.687258661 0.256745785 ... 0.782258451 0.478200883 0.528302252]]
i: 1  delta_loss: 111.583984
  x: [[0.298013031 0.430991352 0.83330965 ... 0.566573262 0.220241114 0.415616632], [-0.268577874 0.549806893 0.205396622 ... 0.625806808 0.3825607 0.422641814]]
  eta: [[0.298013031 0.430991352 0.83330965 ... 0.566573262 0.220241114 0.415616632], [0.149298817 0.549806893 0.205396622 ... 0.625806808 0.3825607 0.422641814]]
  etax: [[0.596026063 0.861982703 1.6666193 ... 1.13314652 0.440482229 0.831233263], [-0.119279057 1.09961379 0.410793245 ... 1.25161362 0.7651214 0.845283628]]
```

The constraint on `eta` should enforce that `x + eta` is positive, but already we see negative values appearing in the first two loops.

Or is this perhaps an issue of the order of updating of variables? For example in the minimise loop I guess it is important that the `x` variables get updated first so that the constraint on the `eta` variables gets calculated correctly? I guess there is no guarantee of that, and I need to tell TensorFlow to do this?

Edit: I attempted to manually clip the variables in the optimisation loop, like so:

```
while delta_loss > tol:
    opt.minimize(get_loss,var_list=eta+x)
    # Manually clip variables
    clip_op = [eta[i].assign(tf.clip_by_value(eta[i], -x[i] + 0.0001, np.infty)) for i in range(N)]
    ...
```

and it seems to kind of work in this case, but in other test cases it seems to make the minimiser go haywire. I guess because it fights with the minimiser about what values the variables should have. So I'm not sure that this is a good solution.

Edit 2: Well for my specific case I realised that I could solve my problem with math, i.e. by a change of variables I can make the problem not require any explicit constraints. Which is probably the best thing to do if it is possible. But it won't always be, so I am still curious how to do it with constraints.